# ffmpeg Insert duplicate audio track without creating intermediate file

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to add a downmixed audio track to existing files.

So normally I do the following commands

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:a -c:a dca -ac 2 -strict -2 -vol 425 stereo.mkv
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i stereo.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:a -map 0:s output.mkv
```

Is there a way I can make a copy of the one and only audio stream in the input at the same time, without having to have an intermediate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:a -map 0:s -c copy -filter:a:1 "volume=425/256" -c:a:1 dca -ac 2 -strict -2 output.mkv`